# How to identify permissions which current user lacks to access node create page?

Tags: 7, users

I have a user with custom role. This role has permission custom-type: create new content.

When I try to access `node/add/custom-type` I am getting 403. Site is quite complex.
What is the quickest way to find which permissions I need to add to this user role to access that page?

Comment: That will surely depend on what custom/contrib access modules you have installed?

Comment: [Devel Node Access (DNA)](https://drupal.org/project/devel) wouldn't work for that, would it?

Comment: @Clive I'm not so sure. "What's wrong" would depend on all that, but "how to find what's wrong" shouldn't, at least if all modules use permission hooks without any dirty hacks. Or am I wrong? It works that way (or seems to me it works) for viewing nodes, Devel Node Access is pretty reliable no matter what contrib modules are in play.

Comment: @Mołot thanks for this module. Now I know that other dev hardcoded access to other user role.

Comment: @drupality so DNA works properly on edit too? If so, I will post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Devel Node Access (DNA)](https://drupal.org/project/devel) provides detailed information on permissions that take effect.

> View the node access entries for the node(s) that are shown on a page. Essential for developers of node access modules and useful for site admins in debugging problems with those modules.

Unless some modules abuse access system with dirty hacks, it should pretty reliably identify which module refused access to given user.

Comment: I didn't check it, no need for this. However, there is no other solution probably.